# PHP: Calculate textbox value via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to calculate text box value via ajax, on event `onkeyup` :

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLHTTP');
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var text = document.getElementById('txtField').value;
  var target = "calc.php";
  var parameter = "txtValue=" + text;

  xmlhttp.open('POST', target, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(parameter);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Price: <input type="text" id="txtField" onkeyup="calc();">
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**calc.php**

```
if ($_POST['txtValue'] && !empty($_POST['txtValue'] )) {
  echo $_POST['txtValue'] * 4;
}
```

But won't show the result. Please tell me what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your calc.php like:

```
if (isset($_POST['txtValue']) && !empty($_POST['txtValue'] )) {
  echo $_POST['txtValue'] * 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following to see if you are getting correct response:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

ok hre is your problem:
use:

```
if (($_POST['txtValue'] != '') && !empty($_POST['txtValue'] ))
```

instead of:

```
if ($_POST['txtValue'] && !empty($_POST['txtValue'] ))
```

cuase $_POST['txtValue'] is not a boolean and can't be used in if condition

Comment: Nothing changed. Alert empty value out

Comment: so now echo something simple from calc.php

Comment: hit calc.php directly in the browser to see if you have any error in your PHP code, use GET or this purpose

Comment: I changed `calc.php` content to `echo 'Ok';` and it works fine, The problem is about `$_POST`. But i have no idea what the problem exactly is

Comment: @HamedKamrava why you used $_POST['txtValue'] in your if condition, use "$_POST['txtValue'] == 1"

Comment: sure but remember always use echo and alert for debugging simple applcations